# LIN bus frame replacement

Tags: serial-communication

I am searching for a way to replace certain frames on a LIN bus network. My aim is to be able to intercept a frame in transmission, and change certain bits. Naturally, that involves recalculating the checksum.

The problem I encounter is that after a bit is overwritten on the bus, the transmitting device stops sending data, as it senses the discrepancy on the bus and assumes there's a collision. Is there a way to overcome that behavior?